# Hide Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, keyboard

I have been trying to hide the keyboard when user enters an activity,i checked and tried various ways and method but the one I lost see is hide keyboard on button click. I don't want the keyboard to hide on only button, I want it to be hidden when the activity starts. I also tried to put the code in an onCreate method but still the same.another on I saw on Android arsenal was to click on any part of the screen to hide the keyboard was nice but still I still prefer the keyboard hidden when the activity starts, please is there any way hiding the keyboard when the activity starts?

Comment: So you have EditTexts in the Activity I'm guessing?

Comment: In your manifest add ths line inside the <activity>  tag add this: **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"**

Answer (score 1):

> **Your solution is here**

There's yet another point of contention to be aware of. By default, Android will automatically assign initial focus to the first `EditText` or focusable control in your `Activity`. It naturally follows that the InputMethod (typically the soft keyboard) will respond to the focus event by showing itself. The **windowSoftInputMode** attribute in **AndroidManifest.xml**, when set to **stateAlwaysHidden**, instructs the keyboard to ignore this automatically-assigned initial focus.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Almost unbelievably, it appears to do nothing to prevent the keyboard from opening when you touch the control (unless **`focusable="false"`** and/or **`focusableInTouchMode="false"`** are assigned to the control). Apparently, the windowSoftInputMode setting applies only to automatic focus events, not to focus events triggered from touch events.

Therefore, **`stateAlwaysHidden`** is VERY poorly named indeed. It should perhaps be called **`ignoreInitialFocus`** instead.

Comment: Worked for me! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write this line on oncreate method

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);